# I can't seem to solve this EOL error, Can anyone please show me

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def evaluate(event):
    data = e.get()
    ans.configure(text = "Answer: " + str(eval(data)))

e = Entry(root)

e.bind('<Enter>',evaluate)
e.pack()

ans = Label(root)
ans.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please be a bit more specific what the error is? What error message or unexpected behaviour do you see?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you looked at the value of `data` before passing it to `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply bind the wrong event to your Entry widget. Use this:

```
e.bind('<Return>', evaluate)
```

In `tkinter`, the `<Return>` event is launched when the user hits ENTER key. Whereas the `<Enter>` event is launched when the mouse enters the geometric area of a widget. I know, it's a bit disturbing...

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer if it is correct